# Does Riak (open source) support some form of multi-site replication?

Tags: riak

The site is unclear on this one, only saying

> *Masterless* multi-site replication

Does this imply that there is some master-master or master-slave system to replicate to another site?

What are the other options to back up a single-server or multi-server Riak DB to another site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We only provide multi-site replication in the enterprise product. It is separate feature not present in the open source code. As the description notes, it is not a master-slave system - this allows for nodes to be down at either end.

Riak is partition tolerant because it's eventually consistant (AP in CAP Theorem) however just having nodes in two data centers doesn't give you all the benefits of full replication. You may not have any copies of a particular piece of data in one data center just because you have nodes there. If a data center went down or there was a routing issue on the net, when it became available again the data would eventually become consistant but during the outage the full set of data would not be in both places.

For example, the default bucket property for `r` (read quorum) is `n_val/2 + 1` - this means if you are configured for 3 replicas (`n_val`) at least 2 nodes have to respond. This would mean even if that one data center that was still up had a node with a copy of a piece of data, it wouldn't be considered a valid read because the other two nodes were in the data center that was down.

For information on backing up a Riak cluster see: http://wiki.basho.com/Backups.html

If you have specific questions, please feel free to contact us on the riak-users mailing list:

http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com

Comment: Wow. I missed that link on backups; and therefore the option that I can Rsync the appends of the logs to another site (though I have a question on that!). Are you a Basho employee?

Comment: @aitchnyu - yup. I started with Basho on Jan 1 of this year.

Comment: (Sorry, should have added) So - for your question on backing up the append logs, just throw us a question on the mailing list. I'm still in the *learn everything* mode along with my day-to-day programming tasks so I'm far from being an expert on everything, but everyone on the engineering team reads and replies to the list.

Comment: Yes, the engineering team **are** reputed for that. Thanks. Hope more of your team listen in on StackOverflow too.

Answer (score 0):

Masterless means exactly that. There is no one master node and therefore no slave nodes in the system.

Riak partitions your data among whatever servers (Basho people call them nodes) you give it and then it replicates, by default, each node's data to 2 other nodes. In essence, if your nodes are in separate data centres, then your data is replicated to multiple sites automatically.

There are few extra details I've left out, like virtual nodes and I'm willing to expand on that, if you need it. The gist of my answer, though, is servers in multiple data centres added to the system and managed by Riak will give you multi-site replication.

Comment: The multi datacenter replication feature is only in the Enterprise version. Not sure how the system can tell the difference, or if it's just that there are extra addons to make this work better.

Comment: I'm unsure, but I'd surmise it's the latter. There's no way it can tell where the IP address of a node is located, IMO.

Comment: @SrdjanPejic - Riak is partition tolerant because it's eventually consistant (AP in CAP Theorem), however just having nodes in two data centers doesn't give you all the benefits of full replication. You may not have any copies of a particular piece of data in one data center just because you have nodes there. If a data center went down or there was a routing issue on the net, when it became available again the data would *eventually* become consistant but during the outage the full set of data would not be in both places

Comment: So open source version can still do multi-site replication, but just not as good as the enterprise version? Is the difference mainly the number of replicas? What other differences are there? @BrianRoach